# SQL Server openrowset() test column count in MS Access table

Tags: t-sql, ms-access, linked-server, openrowset

Haven't found an answer via Google.  I need to execute this code from SQL Server stored proc.

I have a folder with 100+ access dbs with a table called tblReports.  Some of the access db's have an extra column in tblReports called AdminReport.

I need to capture the extra column if it exists, thus... I need to test how many columns are in tblReports so that I can use an if/else statement in the sp to generate the correct sql based on the column count.

I'd love to read your thoughts, here's the relevant snippet.

```
set @sql = 'Insert into CustomerServiceIntranet.dbo.ReportCriteria
            (UserInfo,RptNbr,RptType,RptDesc,GroupCDBrk,ClientCDBrk,CategoryCDBrk,
            UserIDBrk,UnitCDBrk,WrkTypeBrk,StatCDBrk,StatDatBrk,
            ExperBrk,GroupList,ClientList,CategoryList,UserIDList,BusAreaList,
            WrkTypList,StatusList,QueueList,ReviewDay,ReviewDayNA,
            ErrorImpact,DateRange,DataSource,RptPathFile)' 
        + 'Select '''+ @userfilename + ''', ors.* ' 
        + 'from (select * From Openrowset(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',''' 
        + @CurrentName 
        + ''';''Admin'';,''select * from tblReports'')) ors'
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard approach would be to link to tblReports by calling DoCmd.TransferDatabase. You would then be able to count number of the fields in the table, before embarking on any SQL. At the end of the look you would delete the link by calling DoCmd.DeleteObject.

It certainly looks neater than what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm doing this from SQL Server, not MS Access.  Are you saying I can issue a VBA command from SQL Server?  Using openrowset()?

Comment: Sorry, I did not realise that you are trying to do this from SQL Server. It would certainly be easier to do it from VBA though, if that is an option.

Comment: yeah, I needed performance (runs against 100+ databasesin 20 sec) and reusability.  I have the sp all ready to go (and working if I ignore the last/extra column).